# email piping works, but it still returns an error

Tags: php, email, pipe

I am trying to pipe an email to a php script, in order to process the email automatically.
I know I got the piping to work, because I receive an email send to me from the php script, but I also receive an error message saying:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

pipe to |/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/myUserName/domains/myDomain.nl/public_html/api/pipe.php
generated by forwarder@myDomain.nl
```

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this problem?
Because I obviously don't want the sender of the message to get an error message returned, especially if the piping works.

EDIT:

This might be information you'd like to know as well...
My webhost is using DirectAdmin.
I am not running the server myself, so I am unable to edit any config files.

EDIT 2:

php file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php

    // read from stdin
    $fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
    $email = "";
    while(!feof($fd))
    {
        $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fd);

    mail('my@email.nl', 'From my email pipe!', $email);
?>
```

Comment: Could you add the PHP script?

Comment: Sure thing, I added it to my question